# redirect console outout to text field and buttons to console input with java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have this code below divided into 3 class and I want the console output to be display in the text field in the Graphique interface and  the input to be entered from the Grafique interface, not from my keyboard I made all buttons that I need in the interface :
enter button, numbers buttons, clear button, and quiet button

Main Class :

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        AtmProgram account = new AtmProgram();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            int menuOption;
            boolean continueInput = true;

            System.out.println("************************************************");
            System.out.println("1.Solde");
            System.out.println("2.Dépôt");
            System.out.println("3.Retrait");
            System.out.println("4.Quitter");
            System.out.println("************************************************");
            System.out.print("Entrer Menu Option(et press Entrer):");

            while(!input.hasNext()){
                input.next();
            }
            menuOption = input.nextInt();

            switch(menuOption){
                //Solde
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("SOLDE");
                    System.out.println(account.toString());
                    break;
                //Depot
                case 2:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Dépôt");
                        System.out.println(account.toString());
                        System.out.print("Entrez le montant du dépôt:");

                        while(!input.hasNextDouble()){
                            input.next();

                        }
                        double montant_A_Deposer = input.nextDouble();
                        continueInput = false;

                        account.depot(montant_A_Deposer);
                        System.out.println("Nombre de dépôts: "+account.depotCount);
                        System.out.println(account.toString());

                    } catch (IOException ex){

                        System.out.printf("Erreur: vérifiez soit votre entrée (nombre négatif), dépôt maximum par transaction (40K), fréquence de dépôt maximum (4)\n",ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){

                        System.out.printf("Dépôt maximum par jour atteint\n",ex.getMessage());

                    }

                    break;
                //Retrait
                case 3:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("RETRAIT");
                        System.out.println(account.toString());
                        System.out.print("Entrez le montant du retrait:");

                        while(!input.hasNextDouble()){
                            input.next();

                        }
                        double montant_A_Retirer = input.nextDouble();
                        account.retrait(montant_A_Retirer);
                        System.out.println("Nombre de retraits: "+account.retraitCount);
                        System.out.println(account.toString());
                    } catch(Exception e){

                        System.out.printf("Exception lors du retrait\n",e.getMessage());
                    }

                    break;
                //Quitter
                case 4:
                    try {
                        System.out.print("Voulez-vous vraiment QUITTER? (O / N)");
                        if(input.next().equals("O")){
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex){

                        System.out.printf("Exception à quitter",ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Option de Menu non valide");

            }
        } while(true);
    }
}
```

AtmProgram Class :

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AtmProgram {
    private double solde;
    private  double totalRetrait;
    private  double totalDepot;
    protected   int retraitCount;
    protected   int depotCount;
    private final double MAX_DEPOT_PAR_JOUR = 150000.00;
    private final double MAX_DEPOT_PAR_TRANSACTION = 40000.00;
    private final  int MAX_DEPOT_FREQUENCE = 4;
    private final double MAX_RETRAIT_PAR_JOUR = 50000.00;
    private final double MAX_RETRAIT_PAR_TRANSACTION = 20000.00;
    private final int MAX_RETRAIT_FREQUENCE = 4;

    //Constricteur
    public AtmProgram(){
        solde = 0.00;
        totalRetrait = 0.00;
        totalDepot = 0.00;
        retraitCount = 0;
        depotCount = 0;
    }
    //Solde actuel
    public String toString() {
        return "Solde actuel:" + solde;
    }
    //Getters
    public double getSolde(){
        System.out.printf("\nCurrent Balance:%.2f\n",solde);
        return solde;
    }
    public double getTotalRetrait(){
        System.out.printf("\nTotal Withdrawals:%.2f\n",totalRetrait);
        return totalRetrait;
    }
    public  double getTotalDepot(){
        System.out.printf("\nTotal Deposits:%.2f\n",totalDepot);
        return totalDepot;
    }

    public double depot(double montant) throws IOException,Exception{

        if (montant > 0.00 && montant <= MAX_DEPOT_PAR_TRANSACTION && depotCount < MAX_DEPOT_FREQUENCE) {

            depotCount++;

        } else {

            throw new IOException();
        }

        totalDepot = totalDepot + montant;

        if(totalDepot <= MAX_DEPOT_PAR_JOUR){

            solde = solde  + montant;

        } else {

            throw new Exception();

        }

        return solde;

    }

    public double retrait(double montant) throws IOException,Exception {
        if (montant > 0.00 && montant < solde && retraitCount < MAX_RETRAIT_FREQUENCE && montant <= MAX_RETRAIT_PAR_TRANSACTION) {

            retraitCount++;

        } else {

            throw new IOException();
        }

        totalRetrait = totalRetrait + montant;

        if(totalRetrait <= MAX_RETRAIT_PAR_JOUR){

            solde = solde - montant;

        } else {

            throw new Exception();
        }

        return solde;
    }




}
```

Interface Class :

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface {
    private JPanel ATM_Interface;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton entrerButton;
    private JButton correctionButton;
    private JButton quitterButton;
    private JButton btn0;
    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JButton btn3;
    private JButton btn4;
    private JButton btn5;
    private JButton btn6;
    private JButton btn7;
    private JButton btn8;
    private JButton btn9;


    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't use Exceptions for flow control, and if you do, use Exceptions that make sense. How do you figure it makes sense to throw an IOException if your input is invalid?

Comment: And .. what is the question?

Comment: unlike what you stated in your question, it doesn't seem like you have created a UI. Declaring a button, and having a button you can use is far from the same. Also, you should not make all your instance variables public, that's very bad design. Basically, you want us to write UI code and link your business logic to it?

Comment: The console app is working well

Comment: But I want to link it with grafique interface so the same thing that I do in the console with my keyboard I want to do it with grafique interface

Comment: *"The console app is.."* Tip: Add @Stultuske (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @NoureddineEttalhaouy so alter your code that it uses your UI. We understand the goal, you just can't assume that by putting a button somewhere you'll have a working UI without writing additional code.

Comment: @Stultuske exactly

Comment: @Stultuske I already made the all buttons and field text but it dosn't affect they do not anything

Comment: of course they don't. You declared them within a Bean, not within a UI component, you also haven't written any code that instantiated or uses them, so how do you expect them to work?
Next to that, you haven't changed anything about your business logic, so how exactly do you think it'll be contacting a UI? magic?

Comment: @Stultuske i know i have to change the business logic but first i want numbers that in clcked to be displayed in text field and then go ahead with logic

Comment: @NoureddineEttalhaouy so, you want the result before the cause? Do you understand how ... impossible that is?

Comment: Event-driven code is different from console input / output code.  You have to create a GUI from the beginning of your code.  Oracle has a keen tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) that will show you how to construct a proper GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.